# Is it possible with Java to delete to the Recycle Bin?

Tags: java, recycle-bin

**Java** is the key here. I need to be able to delete files but users expect to be able to "undelete" from the recycle bin.  As far as I can tell this isn't possible.  Anyone know otherwise?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For various reasons Windows [has no concept of a folder that simply corresponds to the Recycle Bin](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/18/8956382.aspx).

The correct way is to use JNI to invoke the Windows `SHFileOperation` API, setting the `FO_DELETE` flag in the `SHFILEOPSTRUCT` structure.

- [SHFileOperation documention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164(VS.85).aspx)
- [Java example for copying a file using SHFileOperation](http://www.jroller.com/ethdsy/entry/using_windows_explorer_copy) (the Recycle Bin link in the same article doesn't work)

Comment: This works like a charm! You can also move to Mac OS X Trash.

Comment: It doesn't work with iso-8859-1 encoding, if your program is used on a computer using special characters (éèàñ...) in the path it won't work... but it's fine on an english computer

Comment: @PaulLammertsma Which one works for Mac OS X, John's answer or drye's?

Comment: IIRC, the second link ("Send To Recycle Bin") works on both Windows and OS X because it simply executes the default action for deleting a file with flag `FOF_ALLOWUNDO`.

Comment: Anything that uses `SHFileOperation` can't work on OS X because `SHFileOperation` is a Windows' API.

Comment: @JohnTopley So it doesn't work on _Mac OS X_ ? if so, do you know any other way that works on Macs too?

Answer (score 34):

Ten years later, with Java 9, finally there is a builtin way to move files to the Trash Bin

[`java.awt.Desktop.moveToTrash(java.io.File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#moveToTrash-java.io.File-):

> #### `public boolean moveToTrash​(File file)`
>
> Moves the specified file to the trash.
>
> #### Parameters:
>
> file - the file
>
> #### Returns:
>
> returns true if successfully moved the file to the trash.

The availability of this feature for the underlying platform can be tested with `Desktop.isSupported​(Desktop.Action.MOVE_TO_TRASH)`.

Answer (score 5):

Java 9 has new method but in my case I am restricted to Java 8. 
I found **Java Native Access Platform** that has **hasTrash()** and **moveToTrash()** method. I tested it on Win 10 and Mac OS (Worked) for me.

```
static boolean moveToTrash(String filePath) {
        File file = new File(filePath);

        FileUtils fileUtils =  FileUtils.getInstance();
        if (fileUtils.hasTrash()) {

            try {
                fileUtils.moveToTrash(new File[] { file });
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Trash");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Maven Repository
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna-platform/5.1.0

Don't confuse It is **Java Native Access Platform** not Java Native Access

Answer (score 2):

See the [fileutil](https://jdic.dev.java.net/incubator/fileutil/index.html) incubator project (part of the [Java Desktop Integration Components](https://jdic.dev.java.net/) project):

> This incubator project is created to host those file utility functionalities, most of which are extensions to the java.io.File class in J2SE. There are frequent requests from Java developers for such features like: **sending a file to trash bin**, checking free disk space, accessing file attributes etc. This project addresses such frequently requested APIs.

Note, this should work not only on Windows, but on other platforms (Linux, Mac OS X) as well.

Comment: Neither link works. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709492/java-on-windows-how-to-delete-a-file-to-trash-using-jna) is an example

Answer (score 0):

My 3 cents - use cmd util [Recycle.exe](http://www.maddogsw.com/cmdutils/) with -f to force recycle (no prompt). Works perfectly.

```
public class Trash {

    public void moveToTrash(File ... file) throws IOException {
        moveToTrash(false, file);
    }

    public void promptMoveToTrash(File ... file) throws IOException {
        moveToTrash(true, file);
    }

    private void moveToTrash(boolean withPrompt, File ... file) throws IOException {
        String fileList = Stream.of(file).map(File::getAbsolutePath).reduce((f1, f2)->f1+" "+f2).orElse("");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Recycle.exe "+(withPrompt ? "" : "-f ")+fileList);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JNA platform, the `FileUtils` doesn't use Win32 API. You should prefer `W32FileUtils` which supports Undo (restore the file from recycle bin).

*Edit: as of the current version of JNA Platform (5.7.0), with FileUtils.getInstance(), this statement has become incorrect, and FileUtils will use the Win32 API.*