# Java on Windows: how to delete a file to trash (using JNA)

Tags: java, windows, jna

I'm not experiences with Windows API at all, so please excuse my ignorance.

I want to delete files to the trash. How to do that using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) and how to detect if this would not be possible, e.g., because the files are located on a network share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`com.sun.jna.platform.win32.W32FileUtils`](http://twall.github.com/jna/3.4.1/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/W32FileUtils.html), which has `moveToTrash` and `hasTrash` methods defined.

Comment: where does this package exist ?

Answer (score 9):

Use `com.sun.jna.platform.FileUtils` instead of `com.sun.jna.platform.win32.W32FileUtils` directly.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.sun.jna.platform.FileUtils;

public class MoveToTrash {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        FileUtils fileUtils = FileUtils.getInstance();
        if (fileUtils.hasTrash()) {
            try {
                fileUtils.moveToTrash( new File[] {new File("c:/temp/dummy.txt") });                
            }
            catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No Trash available");
        }
    }
}
```