# Does Java 7 have a way to put files in recycle bin rather than delete on Windows

Tags: java, windows, recycle-bin

Does Java 7 have a way to put files in recycle bin rather than delete on WIndows ?
I know it doesn't exist in Java 6, but I really thought this was getting added to Java 7 but have been unable to find it, if not is there a 3rd party library available to do this, I don't want to fiddle with JNI myself.

FWIW you can do this on OSX using the Apple extension

```
com.apple.eawt.FileManager.moveToTrash()
```

**EDIT:**
Used the jna library as in answer.
FWIW it is available on maven central repository, but you need to include both the jna pom and the platform pom, as the platform jar is the one that contains the recycle bin method.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Possibly an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11106902/829571

Comment: And another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709492/java-on-windows-how-to-delete-a-file-to-trash-using-jna

Comment: Was hoping something had changed

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm very happy this all but useless feature is not supported.

Comment: You think a recycle bin is useless, why you'll never delete anthing my mistake and nor will your users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the answer is No.

3rd party libraries exist, and this is supported in JNA (see [Java on Windows: how to delete a file to trash (using JNA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709492/java-on-windows-how-to-delete-a-file-to-trash-using-jna)), but this functionality is not part of the **standard Java 7 platform**, AFAIK.

This RFE tends to confirm this: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5080625

Comment: That link doesn't make much sense, does that sun class always exist on Windows or it got be created.

Comment: @PaulTaylor - that link/functionality is part of the [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) project.

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn't realize this was what JNA was I thought it was just a newer version of JNI, I'll give this a go here is a updated link a sit has moved to GitHub https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md