# Where do the deleted files go after getting deleted in Run-Time in a Java Program?

Tags: java, file, oop, file-handling, delete-file

I have deleted some Files in a Java Program, but I was surprised to see them missing in Recycle Bin? I'm not using any of the IDEs, and is there any way to recover those files?

Comment: The Recycle Bin is a special folder from the OS. Deleting files removes them from the hard disk completely.

Comment: No, but if you want to move files to Trash in the future,`java 9` has an API for it called [moveToTrash](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#moveToTrash-java.io.File-). Below Java 9 you'll have to use JNI.

Comment: @CodingOtaku make that an answer, as many may search for such relative new and tiny functionality

Comment: @JoopEggen okay, I wrote one, I don't usually write answers, if it require more details/ corrections feel free to edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Answer your question, No. Deleting files removes them from the hard disk completely.

---

But if you want to **move** files to Trash in the future, `Java 9` has an API for it called [moveToTrash](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#moveToTrash-java.io.File-).
Below `Java 9` you'll have to use JNA or libraries that makes use of it like `FileUtils`.

A related question in stackoverflow - [Is it Possible with Java to Delete to the Recycle Bin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/222463)

Comment: `Desktop.getDesktop().moveFileToTrash(new File("biography.txt"));`