# Using Java can I programmatically undelete a file under Windows?

Tags: java, windows, recycle, undelete

I'm successfully using Desktop.getDesktop().moveToTrash(File) under MacOS to delete files and then retrieve them from the Trash folder. I'd like to do the same under Windows. But I don't see a native Java way to access to Recycle Bin so I can undelete them.

Under MacOS I simply rename files from the Trash folder back to where they were. Is there a way I can do that with the Windows Recycle Bin? Or do something similar?

Comment: Have you tried checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222463/is-it-possible-with-java-to-delete-to-the-recycle-bin)?

Comment: There be dragons. It's possible to see the top level folders in C drive recycle bin with `Files.list(Path.of("C:\\$Recycle.Bin")).forEach(System.out::println)`. However your app needs administrator access to view sub-dirs. You may need [WinAPI](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2783/How-to-programmatically-use-the-Recycle-Bin) route (JNI/JNA/JDK Panama) to implement, unless others know of a Java class.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing in the core API. You have a bunch of options.

### But first.. there's trash, and delete

"move to trash" means the file is literally undestroyable - as long as it is remains in the trashcan it remains on your disk. Said differently, if you have a completely filled up harddisk, trash 100GB worth of files, that disk is... still completely filled up. Possibly certain OSes have a 'bot' that runs when needed or on a schedule that truly deletes files in the trashcan that fit certain rules (such as 'deleted more than 30 days ago').

"Actually delete" means the disk space is now available - if you have a full disk, actually delete 100GB worth of files, then there's now 100GB available, **but those files are STILL on disk!!** - the only thing that 'delete' does, is flag the space. It doesn't overwrite the actual bits on disk with zeroes or random data or whatnot. Further use of this disk will eventually mean some other file is written 'over' the deleted file at which point it truly becomes entirely unrecoverable, but if you have some extremely sensitive data, you delete the files, then you toss the computer in the garbage bin, **anybody who gets their hands on that machine can trivially recover your data**. Because what 'delete' does is set a flag "I am deleted", nothing more. All you need to do to undo this, is to unset the flag.

The reason I mention this, is because you used the term 'undelete' in your question. Which usually means something else.

| Verb | UnVerb | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Trash | Recover, Untrash, Restore, Put Back | Disk space remains unavailable. File visible in OS trash can tool |
| Delete | **Undelete** | Disk space is now available; data is still on disk but could be overwritten at any time. |
| Wipe | *N/A* | Data is overwritten with zeroes. Some wiping tools overwrite 7 times with random data to be really sure<sup>1</sup> |
| Trim | *N/A* | Pulse all cells on an SSD<sup>2</sup> - intended to make data unrecoverable, applies only to SSDs |

[1] This fights largely hypothetical trickery where you recover data by scanning for minute magnetic differences in potential. If it's doable at all it requires equipment that costs multiple millions. Still, if you're paranoid, you write random data, and repeat that procedure 7 to 30 times.

[2] SSDs are 'weird' in that they are overprovisioned: They can store more data than the label says. It's because SSDs work in 'cells' and there's a limit to how often a cell can be rewritten. Eventually a cell is near death (it's clear it's only got a few rewrites left in it), at which point the data is copied to an unused cell, and the near-death cell is marked off as no longer usable. The SSD is a 'fake harddrive', exposing itself as a simple contiguous block of writable and addressable space. It's like a mini computer, and will map write ranges to available cells. As a consequence, using basic OS/kernel driver calls to tell the SSD to write 7x random data over a given range of bits **does not actually work**, in that it is possible that there's a cell with the file data that's been marked as not to be used, and it won't be wiped. While somewhat hard to do, you can send special commands, so-called TRIM commands, to most SSDs to explicitly tell them to pulse-clear **all** cells on the **entire drive**, even the ones that have been marked as near-death. This low-level call to the SSD firmware is the only way to securely delete anything off of an SSD. Naturally, the whole *point* of this exercise is that you can't undo it.

So, to be clear, the one and only thing on this list that is meaningfully doable without writing extremely complex software that scans the raw disk out, byte for byte (which is a tool you should not be writing in java, as you'll be programming a lot towards the OS/arch which java is not good at), is the **Untrash** part: Undoing the 'trash' action.

### Not available in basic java

... unfortunately even that is not available normally. There's an API to tell the OS to 'trash' a file, there is no API call to untrash it. That means you'll have to code an implementation for untrashing for *each and every OS you want to support*. On mac, you could handroll it by moving files out of `~/.Trash`. On windows its a little trickier.

One "simple" (heh) way is to use [JNI](https://www.baeldung.com/jni) to write C code (targeting the windows API, to be compiled on windows with windows oriented C tools) that does the job, and then use JNI to call this C function (compiled to a `.dll`) on windows specifically. You can ship the DLL and simply not use it on non-windows OSes. You will have to compile this DLL once for every arch you want to target (presumably, x64, possibly x86 and aarch64 (ARM)). This is all highly complicated and requires some knowledge about how to write fairly low-level windows code.

### Use command line tools

You can invoke command line tools. For example, windows has fsutil which can be used to make hard links. I *think* you can do it - `C:\$Recycle.bin` is the path, more or less. Where C is itself already a little tricky to attempt to find from java (you can have multiple disks in a system, so do you just scan for C:, D:, etc? But if the machine still has a CD-ROM drive that'll make it spin up which surely you didn't want. You can ask windows about what kind of disk a letter is, but this again requires JNI, it's not baked into java).

You could write most of the untrash functionality in a powershell script and then simply use java's `ProcessBuilder` to run it, and have it do the bulk of the work.

### Use `C:\$Recycle.bin`

You can try accessing `Paths.get("C:\$Recycle.bin")` and see what happens. Presumably, you can just move files out of there. But note that each file has associated with it, knowledge of where it used to be. The files still have their extension but their names are mangled, containing only the drive letter they came from + a number. There's a separate mapping file that tells you where the file was deleted from and what its name was. You will have to open this mapping file and parse through it. You'll have to search the web to figure out what the format of this mapping file is. You'll have to take care not to corrupt it, and probably to remove the file you just recovered from it (without corrupting it).

Note that files in the recycle bin have all sorts of flags set, such as the system flag. You may have to write it all in powershell or batch scripts, and start those from java instead, to e.g. run `ATTRIB.EXE` to change properties first. Hopefully you can do it with the `java.nio.file` API which exposes some abilities to interact with windows-specific file flag stuff.

### Build your own trashcan

In general it's a bad idea to use java to write highly-OS-specific tooling. You can do it, but it'll hurt the entire time. The designers of java didn't make it for this (Project Panama is trying to fix this, but it's not in JDK18 and won't be in 19 either, it's a few years off – and it wasn't really designed for this kind of thing either), and your average java coder wouldn't use it for this, so that means: Few to no libraries, and hard to find support.

Hence, it's a better idea to consider desktop java apps to do things more in its own way than your average desktop tool. Which can include 'having its own trashcan'. Let's say you have a code editor written in java, and it has a 'delete' feature. You're free to implement 'delete' by moving files to a trashcan dir *you* made, where *you* track (Via a DB or shadow files) when the delete occurred, who did it, and where the file came from. Then *you* build code that can move it back, and code that 'empties the trash', possibly on a schedule.

You can do all that simply with `Files.move`.

Comment: “You can ask windows about what kind of disk a letter is, but this again requires JNI…” `Files.getFileStore(Path.of(driveLetter)).isReadOnly()` may identify optical media readers.

Comment: @VGR try it; the actual abilities of those kinds of methods are usually disappointing. I vaguely recall last time I checked it, didn't work (I don't have access to a windows machine to test it myself right at this moment). There are also various methods in swing's JFileChooser stuff, none of which work.

Comment: Many thanks for that excellent, excellent discussion, rzwitserloot. I think I'm leaning toward rolling my own Trashcan. Wonder why the Windows boffins decided to do things this way.