# desktop.moveToTrash(srcFile); not for Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Unfortunately I am limited to Java 8 in my application and cannot use newer versions. I can't find any documentation on how to move a file to the recycle bin in Java 8.

I know about

```
desktop.moveToTrash(srcFile);
```

but this is not for Java 8.

Comment: Note that the duplicate contains *both* Java 9+ answers and answers for previous versions.

Comment: For example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53388438/507738) is for Java 8.